# Advanced heading styles in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible to do either of the following things:

1. Add a background image to a heading style
2. Add a rounded rectangle shape in the heading style where the text is in

Note that this has to be a *heading* style, so every time this specific style is used, the same background image has to be displayed (or the background has to be solid with rounded corners).

I've looked everywhere and it seems you can do this in the header of your document but not in headings/chapter titles.

Comment: Which version of Word?

Comment: @JulianKnight 2013 is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Autotext to save and insert content of your choosing:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the video tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of possible to do but only manually.

Insert an image of the correct size and set "Text Wrapping" to "Behind Text". Make sure that the Position settings include "Move object with text". Now the image will be behind the text and will move with it.

However, you have to do this for every entered heading, you cannot make it part of the style.